Application.Match not recognizing matches
Have this long convoluted program, called when a cell in the relevant column on a given sheet is changed, for the purpose of identifying cases where there are duplicates in the WO value (column D) and keeping them together while sorting by other values (as an exception to the general sorting rules I am implementing), so long as their District value (column c) is the same. The way I am trying to do this is by using a helper column where (after all of the other sorting is done) I assign each row an integer in order, then if the program sees a duplicate WO value where the district is also the same, it changes the helper column value to the same number as the first instance of that WO in that district, and then the sheet will sort by that column last.
The program seems to be working as intended up until I try to assign a value to pos and it always comes up as an error, even when the WO is a duplicate and I have verified that it is in dupArray. I have also verified that wo and search are both strings.
EDIT: Adding example table of data being sorted, relevant columns are District, WO#, and Order Helper (the helper column). In this example, while the table is being primarily sorted by district and priority, because there are 2 instances of WO# 123 in Los Angeles, the order helper value of the second instance is reassigned from 5 to 3 and then resorted so it remains grouped with the other instance.



Due Date
Days Until Due
DISTRICT
WO#
Assigned
Facility
Description
PRIORITY
Extra
DATE RECEIVED
Order Helper




2024-11-22
OVERDUE
New York
123
Yes
n/a
n/a
A

10/1/2024
1


2024-12-26
0
New York
345
No
n/a
n/a
B

10/1/2024
2


2024-11-26
OVERDUE
Los Angeles
123
No
n/a
n/a
A

10/1/2024
3


2024-11-26
OVERDUE
Los Angeles
123
No
n/a
n/a
B

10/1/2024
3


2024-11-22
OVERDUE
Los Angeles
678
No
n/a
n/a
A

10/1/2024
4



    Public Sub masterWOSort(sheet As String, tb As String)
    With Sheets(sheet)
        Dim wo As String
        Dim tb2 As ListObject
        Set tb2 = .ListObjects(tb)
        Dim count As Integer: count = 0
        Dim t As Long: t = 1
        Dim oc As Integer: oc = 0
        Dim numSave As Integer
        Dim district As String
        For Each rw In tb2.DataBodyRange.Rows    ' put a seRuential number next to each row
            rw.Cells(11).Value = t
            t = t + 1
        Next rw
        
        Dim allWo() As Variant
        ReDim allWo(1 To t - 1)
        Dim c As Integer: c = 1
        For Each rw In tb2.DataBodyRange.Rows
            allWo(c) = rw.Cells(4).Value
            c = c + 1
        Next rw
        
    'make unique list of allWo()
        Dim uniqueWO() As Variant
        uniqueWO() = CreateUniqueList(3, t + 1)
        
        Dim dupArray() As String
        Dim j As Integer: j = 1
        Dim z As Integer: z = 1
        Dim i As Integer: i = 1
        'create pasted ranges
        For Each u In uniqueWO()
            'paste to column whatever row j
            .Cells(j, 30).Value = uniqueWO(j)
            j = j + 1
        Next u
        For Each a In allWo()
            'paste to column whatever row j
            .Cells(z, 31).Value = allWo(z)
            z = z + 1
        Next a
 'determine length of uniqueWo() and allWo()
        Dim ulength As Integer
        ulength = UBound(uniqueWO, 1) - LBound(uniqueWO, 1)
        Dim alength As Integer
        alength = UBound(allWo, 1) - LBound(allWo, 1)
'create ranges of uniqueWo and allWo
        Dim uRng As Range
        Dim uString As String
        uString = "AD1:AD" & ulength
        Set uRng = ActiveSheet.Range(uString)
        Dim aRng As Range
        Dim aString As String
        aString = "AE1:AE" & alength
        Set aRng = ActiveSheet.Range(aString)
 'for each value in the pasted range, check how often it appears in allwo(), if multiple times then put in another array
        For counter = 1 To ulength
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(aRng, uRng.Cells(counter)) > 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve dupArray(1, 1 To i)
                dupArray(0, i) = uniqueWO(counter)
                dupArray(1, i) = 0
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next counter
        
        
        Dim pos As Variant
        Dim search As String
        For Each rw In tb2.DataBodyRange.Rows    ' replace number with the one of the first instance of WO if it is a multiple
            wo = rw.Cells(4).Value
            If IsInArray(wo, dupArray) = True Then
                For z = 1 To UBound(dupArray, 2)
                    On Error Resume Next
                    search = Application.Index(dupArray, 1, z)
                    pos = Application.Match(wo, search, 0)
                    
                    On Error Resume Next
                    dupArray(1, pos) = dupArray(1, pos) + 1
                    If IsError(pos) = False Then Exit For
                Next
                If dupArray(1, pos) = 1 Then
                numSave = rw.Cells(11).Value
                district = rw.Cells(3).Value
                    ElseIf rw.Cells(3).Value = district Then
                        rw.Cells(11).Value = numSave
                End If
            End If
        Next rw
 'delete helper columns for allWo and uniqueWo
        .Columns(30).ClearContents
        .Columns(31).ClearContents
        
    End With
End Sub

Function CreateUniqueList(nStart As Long, nEnd As Long) As Variant
 Dim Col As New Collection
 Dim arrTemp() As Variant
 Dim valCell As String
 Dim i As Integer
 'Populate Temporary Collection
  On Error Resume Next
  For i = 0 To nEnd
  valCell = Range("D" & nStart).Offset(i, 0).Value
  Col.add valCell, valCell
 Next i
 Err.Clear
 On Error GoTo 0
  'Resize n
   nEnd = Col.count
  'Redeclare array
   ReDim arrTemp(1 To nEnd)
  'Populate temporary array by looping through the collection
   For i = 1 To Col.count
     arrTemp(i) = Col(i)
   Next i
  'return the temporary array to the function result
   CreateUniqueList = arrTemp()
End Function

Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
 Dim i
 For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
    If arr(0, i) = stringToBeFound Then
        IsInArray = True
        Exit Function
    End If
 Next i
 IsInArray = False
End Function


How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.

@taller table has been added to the main post, please let me know if anything else would be helpful.

With two For...Next loop the code walk through the rows of the table, and gather the identical rows on the specific cells (District and WO#).
Sub Order(sheet As String, table As String)
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Worksheets(sheet)
Dim dbr As Range
Set dbr = sh.ListObjects(table).DataBodyRange
For base = 1 To dbr.Rows.count - 1
    baserun = base + 1
    For runpoi = baserun To dbr.Rows.count
        If dbr.Cells(base, 3) = dbr.Cells(runpoi, 3) And dbr.Cells(base, 4) = dbr.Cells(runpoi, 4) Then
            dbr.Rows(runpoi).Cut
            dbr.Rows(base + 1).Insert
            base = base + 1
        End If
    Next runpoi
Next base
End Sub



Public Sub masterWOSort(shtName As String, tblName As String)
    
    Dim tb As ListObject, rw As Range
    Dim dict As Object, k, n As Long
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set tb = Sheets(shtName).ListObjects(tblName)
    
    ' Fill helper columm
    For Each rw In tb.DataBodyRange.Rows
       'unique key DISTRICT WO#
       k = rw.Columns(3) & vbTab & rw.Columns(4)
       If dict.exists(k) Then
           rw.Columns(11) = dict(k)
       Else
           n = n + 1
           rw.Columns(11) = n ' Order Helper
           dict.Add k, n
       End If
    Next
    
End Sub

